# how to add text to save image by camera in android app

Tags: android

Im using camera in my android app but I have to add text to save captured image (after capturing image app should ask to add text to save captured image). How can I do this ?

Comment: Why people downvote Android questions so often?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do is to save a note with the image. 
You should create a directory in which you will save the image with say name "image****.jpg". In the same directory create a file with same name but with different extension on no extension at all. (like "image****.txt").

When you access the image file, open the note file seperately and process it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to write text to bitmap from camera...

```
 private Bitmap writeTextBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,String text) {

    Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(20);

    Rect textRect = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    //If the text is bigger than the canvas , reduce the font size
    if(textRect.width() >= (canvas.getWidth() - 4))     //the padding on either sides is considered as 4, so as to appropriately fit in the text
        paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(mContext, 7));        //Scaling needs to be used for different dpi's

    //Calculate the positions
    int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - 2;     //-2 is for regulating the x position offset

    //"- ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)" is the distance from the baseline to the center.
    int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)) ;  

    canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```